# XSL-Transformation: escape tags and keep attributes within this tag

Tags: xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I'm an absolute beginner concerning xsl transformation and I have a problem one of you may can help me with. I have following xml block:

```
<Metrics>
    <Metric name="DocAmount" value="123.21" currency="GBP" type="Total"/>
    <Metric name="Invoices" value="113.21" currency="GBP" type="Total"/>
    <Metric name="Credit" value="10.00" currency="GBP" type="Total"/>
</Metrics>
```

I have to escape the "<" and ">" from the inner elements "Metric" and keep at the same time all attributes with their values => I want to have this:

```
<Metrics>
    &lt;Metric name="DocAmount" value="123.21" currency="GBP" type="Total"/&gt;
    &lt;Metric name="Invoices" value="113.21" currency="GBP" type="Total"/&gt;
    &lt;Metric name="Credit" value="10.00" currency="GBP" type="Total"/&gt;
</Metrics>
```

I already searched here in stackoverflow and found a way to escape the "<" and the ">" but with my xsl template the attributes arn't copied and I get this here:

```
<Metrics>
        &lt;Metric&gt;&lt;/Metric&gt;
        &lt;Metric&gt;&lt;/Metric&gt;
        &lt;Metric&gt;&lt;/Metric&gt;
</Metrics>
```

To get this I used following xsl template definition:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="no" encoding="UTF-8"/> 

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="Metric">      
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('&lt;',name(),'&gt;',.,'&lt;/',name(),'&gt;')" />
   </xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Can anybody help me to setup a correct xsl template doing what I want to have?
Thanks a lot in advance for your help!

Comment: So which XSLT 2 processor do you use? We have XSLT 3 since this year and the current versions of Saxon or Altova support it and then your task is as easy as `<xsl:template match="Metric"><xsl:value-of select="serialize(.)"/></xsl:template>` so perhaps this is a cleaner and easier way. If you want to implement the serialization in XSLT then you need to process the attribute nodes `@*` of your `Metric` elements with `for-each` or `apply-templates`.

Comment: Hi Martin
Thanks a lot for your very useful input! I tried the approach with XSLT 3 and it worked! Now I just have to get rid of the namespace which are inserted on each metric element:

&lt;Metric xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" name="TotalDocAmount" value="123.21" currency="GBP" type="Total"/&gt;

Comment: I don't see any namespace declarations in your XML input snippet so there is no reason the output should have any. Edit your question and show namespace declarations in the input unless doing `<xsl:variable name="copy" as="element(Metric)"><xsl:copy-of select="." copy-namespaces="no"/></xsl:variable><xsl:value-of select="serialize($copy)"/>` fixes the problem.

Comment: Hi Martin, sorry for not posting the complete XML input -- I just didn't know that namespaces will be generated by the transformation ... but yes there is indeed a namespace in the input. 
Again your tip worked perfectly and now no additonal namespaces are generated at all :-) 
Thank you very much for your fast replies and great help!
Have a nice day, cheers Patrik

Comment: I have morphed the comments into an answer so that you can mark your question as solved now that we have established that you can use XSLT 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your question is tagged as XSLT 2 and these days we have XSLT 3 and the main XSLT 2.0 implementations like Saxon 9 with Saxon 9.8 or Altova with Altova 2017 or 2018 have been updated to support XSLT 3 I think the easiest and most elegant solution is to move to XSLT 3 and use the XPath 3 `serialize` function:

```
<xsl:template match="Metric">
  <xsl:value-of select="serialize(.)"/>
</xsl:template>
```

As your comment indicates you have namespaces in your input you don't want to be serialized you can use

```
<xsl:template match="Metric">
  <xsl:variable name="copy" as="element(Metric)"><xsl:copy-of select="." copy-namespaces="no"/></xsl:variable>
  <xsl:value-of select="serialize($copy)"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks for morphing all together into an answer!